# iOS how to make dynamic width / autolayout of UIView according to UILabel within it

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am struggling with maybe a bit of a rookie issue. I have a `UIView` within which I display some price. I want the `UIView` to be of a dynamic width according to the price, if its 1 Euro, then it will be e.g. `20pt`, if its 2300 Euro, then it will be like `50pt` in width.

I was trying to use the storyboard's constraints but without luck. Is it possible to do it within storyboard or do I have to calculate the width of `UILabel` and then set the width of `UIView` programmatically?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in the storyboard. Add a label to your view and pin it to the left and right edge (top and bottom if you want also). Give the view constraints to its superview in the x and y directions, but do not give it a width constraint (it will need a height constraint if you didn't pin the top and bottom of the label to it). The view should then expand with the label depending on its content.

Comment: Hello @rdelmar, can you please  help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103760/applying-autolayout-constraints-to-multiple-objects

Comment: @Ranjit, NavinDev has already answered your question, though you should not add the leading constraint as I said in my comment to his answer.

Comment: When you say give constraints to its superview in the x and y directions, do you mean give it any horizontal and any vertical constraint (relative to its superview)? Thanks @rdelmar!

Answer (score 27):

In general, auto layout is performed in a top-down fashion. In other words, a parent view layout is performed first, and then any child view layouts are performed. So asking the system to size the parent based on the child is a bit like swimming upstream, harder to do, but still possible with some work.

One solution is to use the *intrinsic size* of a view.

For example, a `UILabel` has an intrinsic size based on the text in the label.  If a `UILabel` has a leading constraint and a top constraint, but no other constraints, then its width and height are determined by its intrinsic size.

You can do the same thing with a custom view class that encloses a UILabel. By setting the intrinsic size of the custom view class based on the intrinsic size of the UILabel, you get a view that automatically resizes based on the text in the label.

Here's what the code looks like for the custom class. The `.h` file defines a single property `text`. The `.m` file has an IBOutlet to the child label.  Setting and getting the `text` property simply sets or gets the text from the label.  But there's one very important twist, setting the text invalidates the intrinsic size of the parent. That's what makes the system adjust the size of the parent view.  In the sample code below the parent is sized to have an 8 pixel margin all around the UILabel.

**SurroundView.h**

```
@interface SurroundView : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *text;
@end
```

**SurroundView.m**

```
@interface SurroundView()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *childLabel;
@end

@implementation SurroundView

- (void)setText:(NSString *)text
{
    self.childLabel.text = text;
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}

- (NSString *)text
{
    return( self.childLabel.text );
}

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    CGSize size = self.childLabel.intrinsicContentSize;

    size.height += 16;
    size.width  += 16;

    return( size );
}

@end
```

Creating the IBOutlet to the `childLabel` can be a little tricky, so here's the procedure

- drag out a UIView into the storyboard
- use the Identity inspector to change the class to `SurroundView`
- drag out a UILabel and add it as a subview of the `SurroundView`
- select the label, and open the assistant editor
- show `SurroundView.m` in the assistant
- drag from the open circle to the label as shown below

[image]

All that's left is to get the constraints right. The constraints for the label should look like this

[image]

The constraints for the `SurroundView` should be as shown below.  The key point is that the *Intrinsic Size* should be set to *Placeholder* to avoid the warnings about missing constraints.

[image]

Comment: This is the key - "In general, auto layout is performed in a top-down fashion. In other words, a parent view layout is performed first, and then any child view layouts are performed."

Comment: I often add a width constraint, then change the constraint from = to >= and assign it a lower priority. Kudos to the answer; Intrinsic Size set to Placeholder was a revelation for me.

Answer (score 2):

Place the label inside the view and pin its TOP , BOTTOM , TRAILING and LEADING edges to the labels superview. Note that you do not specify the width constraint. Now add a height and width constraint to the view. Make an outlet to the width constraint and when the price changes set the view's width constraint's constant to your desired value. Since the label is pinned to the view it will expand too.

Comment: Hello @NavinDev can you please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103760/applying-autolayout-constraints-to-multiple-objects